# Google Calendar API for multiple users:

Tags: google-api, google-calendar-api

I am developing a web app in Ruby on Rails for registering talks given in my company. If a user registers for a talk, then it should update the Google Calendar event for all users who have the event on their Google Calendar.

https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2

I need to use OAuth2 since I need to modify the user's data and I need to obtain the consent from the user as well. So I can redirect them to the Authentication page where they can sign in to view their account. But in this case the user data I want to modify is Calendar of all those people who signed up for the event.

Is there any easy way to do this? Like using an admin account?

Answer (score 0):

When you want to update the Google Calendar event for all users who already have event in their calendar, you no need to use OAUTH as user authentication is not required.

This is because, when there is an update in the existing event then all the users (who are all already added as attendee in the existing event) calendar gets updated without users consent screen.

Comment: I get what you mean. I still have to use OAuth for updating the user's calendar to whom the event originally belongs to, right?

Comment: No need to use Oauth just to update the Google Calendar event for all users who already have event in their calendar. When you update the existing event then all the users calendars gets updated.